How to calculate the rotation speed of spinning top, which will be enough that it is not falling down or stays within certain angle to vertical axis
I found many articles with the calculation of the precession rotation speed of the spinning top like this or this. They give this equation for Precession rotation speed $\Omega$:
$$\Omega=\frac{mgr}{I\omega}$$
But my question is different. I am not interested in the Precession rotation speed $\Omega$. I am interested in calculating the spinning top rotation speed $\omega$, which is enough, that spinning top is not falling down or precession stays within the specific angle.
If I consider this picture:

Then the question can be rephrased like this:
What should be the value of $\omega$ (spinning top rotation speed) that angle $\Large\phi$ stays less than some value (for example 5 degrees).
The assumptions:

I know everything about my spinning top (Moment of inertia, mass, etc.)
There is no friction.

More specific example: I have a spinning top, which is almost a ring, 10 grams weight, radius 10 cm. Moment of inertia
$$I=mr^2=0.01kg \times (0.1m)^2=10^{-4}$$
With which speed (RPS or RPM) I should rotate it, that it's axis stays within 5 degrees to vertical?

Related or possible duplicate.
